# how Can i Define The 'poll_id' from 'text'? JSON

Tags: python, arrays, json, instagram, instagram-api

Json:

```
{'broadcast': None, 'reel': {'id': 48480962483, 'latest_reel_media': 1638565906, 'expiring_at': 1638652306, 'seen': 0, 'can_reply': True, 'can_gif_quick_reply': True, 'can_reshare': True, 'reel_type': 'user_reel', 'ad_expiry_timestamp_in_millis': None, 'is_cta_sticker_available': None, 'user': {'pk': 48480962483, 'username': 'slayer.moat1817822927', 'full_name': '', 'is_private': False, 'profile_pic_url': 'https://instagram.fbah9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/209256932_2966793090261180_8562597132411672195_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbah9-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=S-vzoyx42GAAX8ck_CU&edm=ALCvFkgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=8e3aaa1618a1a4c5a21161e0998eb4a1&oe=61B0AAA7&_nc_sid=643ae9', 'profile_pic_id': '2606097318255063120_48480962483', 'friendship_status': {'following': False, 'followed_by': False, 'blocking': False, 'muting': False, 'is_private': False, 'incoming_request': False, 'outgoing_request': False, 'is_bestie': False, 'is_restricted': False, 'is_feed_favorite': False}, 'is_verified': False, 'follow_friction_type': 0}, 'items': [{'taken_at': 1638565875, 'pk': 2720810261227304411, 'id': '2720810261227304411_48480962483', 'device_timestamp': 1638565875995265, 'media_type': 1, 'code': 'CXCQoRhsPXb', 'client_cache_key': 'MjcyMDgxMDI2MTIyNzMwNDQxMQ==.2', 'filter_type': 0, 'is_unified_video': False, 'user': {'pk': 48480962483, 'username': 'slayer.moat1817822927', 'full_name': '', 'is_private': False, 'profile_pic_url': 'https://instagram.fbah9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/209256932_2966793090261180_8562597132411672195_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbah9-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=S-vzoyx42GAAX8ck_CU&edm=ALCvFkgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=8e3aaa1618a1a4c5a21161e0998eb4a1&oe=61B0AAA7&_nc_sid=643ae9', 'profile_pic_id': '2606097318255063120_48480962483', 'is_verified': False, 'follow_friction_type': 0, 'has_anonymous_profile_picture': False, 'is_unpublished': False, 'is_favorite': False, 'has_highlight_reels': False, 'account_badges': []}, 'caption_is_edited': False, 'like_and_view_counts_disabled': False, 'commerciality_status': 'not_commercial', 'is_paid_partnership': False, 'playlist_eligibility': False, 'image_versions2': {'candidates': [{'width': 750, 'height': 1333, 'url': 'https://instagram.fbah9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p750x750/263918314_331780178784749_950319104813069506_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbah9-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=87fn0Oo4ilcAX_oZ62b&edm=ALCvFkgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=76e94683d6349a0937f36046e8fc21d9&oe=61ACEC49&_nc_sid=643ae9&ig_cache_key=MjcyMDgxMDI2MTIyNzMwNDQxMQ%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4', 'scans_profile': 'e35'}, {'width': 249, 'height': 443, 'url': 'https://instagram.fbah9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/p249x249/263918314_331780178784749_950319104813069506_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbah9-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=87fn0Oo4ilcAX_oZ62b&edm=ALCvFkgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=5848171dc9063935cf1476a07cf6e702&oe=61ACCCEE&_nc_sid=643ae9&ig_cache_key=MjcyMDgxMDI2MTIyNzMwNDQxMQ%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4', 'scans_profile': 'e35'}]}, 'original_width': 1242, 'original_height': 2208, 'caption_position': 0.0, 'is_reel_media': True, 'photo_of_you': False, 'can_see_insights_as_brand': False, 'caption': None, 'can_viewer_save': False, 'organic_tracking_token': 'eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImlzX2FuYWx5dGljc190cmFja2VkIjpmYWxzZSwidXVpZCI6ImU3NWUwZmEzYzYwYTRlNTc4NzU3YmFkMWU2MDRkYTMxMjcyMDgxMDI2MTIyNzMwNDQxMSIsInNlcnZlcl90b2tlbiI6IjE2Mzg1NjU5NDgzNTR8MjcyMDgxMDI2MTIyNzMwNDQxMXw1MDY0NTA2OTc1MXwyMzZiNDRiOGI0MDQxOTE5MDU0N2NkNzcyZTU5NWExYmI1M2U5ZjMzMmVjNzJiMzUwYjg2ZTRmYWU0ZjA4OGMzIn0sInNpZ25hdHVyZSI6IiJ9', 'expiring_at': 1638652275, 'sharing_friction_info': {'should_have_sharing_friction': False, 'bloks_app_url': None}, 'product_type': 'story', 'is_in_profile_grid': False, 'profile_grid_control_enabled': False, 'deleted_reason': 0, 'integrity_review_decision': 'pending', 'music_metadata': None, 'can_reshare': True, 'can_reply': True, 'story_polls': [{'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.411684782608695, 'z': 0, 'width': 0.579710144927536, 'height': 0.101902173913043, 'rotation': 0.0, 'is_pinned': 0, 'is_hidden': 0, 'is_sticker': 1, 'is_fb_sticker': 0, 'poll_sticker': {'id': 'polling_sticker_vibrant', 'poll_id': 17944231672643908, 'question': '', 'tallies': [{'text': 'GKZP', 'font_size': 35.0, 'count': 0}, {'text': '7E0O', 'font_size': 35.0, 'count': 0}], 'promotion_tallies': None, 'viewer_can_vote': True, 'is_shared_result': False, 'is_multi_option_poll': False, 'color': 'black', 'finished': False}}], 'story_static_models': [], 'supports_reel_reactions': True, 'can_send_custom_emojis': True, 'show_one_tap_fb_share_tooltip': False}, {'taken_at': 1638565906, 'pk': 2720810511979674200, 'id': '2720810511979674200_48480962483', 'device_timestamp': 1638565906619329, 'media_type': 1, 'code': 'CXCQr7DsnpY', 'client_cache_key': 'MjcyMDgxMDUxMTk3OTY3NDIwMA==.2', 'filter_type': 0, 'is_unified_video': False, 'user': {'pk': 48480962483, 'username': 'slayer.moat1817822927', 'full_name': '', 'is_private': False, 'profile_pic_url': 'https://instagram.fbah9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/209256932_2966793090261180_8562597132411672195_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbah9-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=S-vzoyx42GAAX8ck_CU&edm=ALCvFkgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=8e3aaa1618a1a4c5a21161e0998eb4a1&oe=61B0AAA7&_nc_sid=643ae9', 'profile_pic_id': '2606097318255063120_48480962483', 'is_verified': False, 'follow_friction_type': 0, 'has_anonymous_profile_picture': False, 'is_unpublished': False, 'is_favorite': False, 'has_highlight_reels': False, 'account_badges': []}, 'caption_is_edited': False, 'like_and_view_counts_disabled': False, 'commerciality_status': 'not_commercial', 'is_paid_partnership': False, 'playlist_eligibility': False, 'image_versions2': {'candidates': [{'width': 750, 'height': 1333, 'url': 'https://instagram.fbah9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p750x750/263454369_205333548440690_7054250030803138253_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbah9-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=fYKgla9WIWwAX8Sdevo&edm=ALCvFkgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=956e32f5d9c6153dd93f069c9ff3611b&oe=61AD22CE&_nc_sid=643ae9&ig_cache_key=MjcyMDgxMDUxMTk3OTY3NDIwMA%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4', 'scans_profile': 'e35'}, {'width': 249, 'height': 443, 'url': 'https://instagram.fbah9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/p249x249/263454369_205333548440690_7054250030803138253_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fbah9-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=fYKgla9WIWwAX8Sdevo&edm=ALCvFkgBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=8fa4322c1da36fd0e919c94a8975ef14&oe=61AD0086&_nc_sid=643ae9&ig_cache_key=MjcyMDgxMDUxMTk3OTY3NDIwMA%3D%3D.2-ccb7-4', 'scans_profile': 'e35'}]}, 'original_width': 1242, 'original_height': 2208, 'caption_position': 0.0, 'is_reel_media': True, 'photo_of_you': False, 'can_see_insights_as_brand': False, 'caption': None, 'can_viewer_save': False, 'organic_tracking_token': 'eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImlzX2FuYWx5dGljc190cmFja2VkIjpmYWxzZSwidXVpZCI6ImU3NWUwZmEzYzYwYTRlNTc4NzU3YmFkMWU2MDRkYTMxMjcyMDgxMDUxMTk3OTY3NDIwMCIsInNlcnZlcl90b2tlbiI6IjE2Mzg1NjU5NDg0MDd8MjcyMDgxMDUxMTk3OTY3NDIwMHw1MDY0NTA2OTc1MXwzMDc2MWJmYzg5NmVkNDdjYTkwMjRjY2I5YTc5ZWU5YWU2MDgzYmU5Mjc5MmJkOWJlNzgyZDM3ZTU5M2E2MzgwIn0sInNpZ25hdHVyZSI6IiJ9', 'expiring_at': 1638652306, 'sharing_friction_info': {'should_have_sharing_friction': False, 'bloks_app_url': None}, 'product_type': 'story', 'is_in_profile_grid': False, 'profile_grid_control_enabled': False, 'deleted_reason': 0, 'integrity_review_decision': 'pending', 'music_metadata': None, 'can_reshare': True, 'can_reply': True, 'story_polls': [{'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.411684782608695, 'z': 0, 'width': 0.579710144927536, 'height': 0.101902173913043, 'rotation': 0.0, 'is_pinned': 0, 'is_hidden': 0, 'is_sticker': 1, 'is_fb_sticker': 0, 'poll_sticker': {'id': 'polling_sticker_vibrant', 'poll_id': 17910086183116991, 'question': '', 'tallies': [{'text': 'L7M', 'font_size': 35.0, 'count': 0}, {'text': 'DGAG', 'font_size': 35.0, 'count': 0}], 'promotion_tallies': None, 'viewer_can_vote': True, 'is_shared_result': False, 'is_multi_option_poll': False, 'color': 'black', 'finished': False}}], 'story_static_models': [], 'supports_reel_reactions': True, 'can_send_custom_emojis': True, 'show_one_tap_fb_share_tooltip': False}], 'prefetch_count': 0, 'has_besties_media': False, 'media_count': 2, 'media_ids': [2720810261227304411, 2720810511979674200], 'has_fan_club_media': False}, 'status': 'ok'}
```

and now i wanna define 'poll_id' from the 'text', if your wodnering why just i define 'poll_id' its because of some times theres many 'poll_id's so yea

Comment: What you mean with define `poll_id` from the text?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.